# C++ sound creation/manipulation library?

Tags: c++, audio

I'm not quite sure what the thing I'm looking for would be called(a sound engine)? Basically I'm creating an application to help with musical ear training, and so I need a library that will generate the various pitches that could be found(ie. a, a#, b, c, c#, d, d#, e....). I appreciate any help you could give.

Answer (score 2):

My two favoruite C++ audio librarys are [bass](http://www.un4seen.com/) and [FMOD](http://www.fmod.org/)

Comment: Thanks I'll check them out :)

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these:

Bass : http://www.un4seen.com/

OpenAL : http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/default.aspx

FMOD: http://www.fmod.org/

Answer (score 0):

I would also take a look at

http://puredata.info/ 
http://libpd.cc/

libpd is based on pure data but can be implemented in applications without pure datas user interface.
so first you build a graphical patch in pure data and than you implement it in your app using libpd. It is possible to write extensions for pure data in C or C++.